# What's the best way to get a registration hash for a user?

Tags: django, email, registration

I am working on a user registration link and I think that after the user registers, I would send an email with the link for adding more info. What's the best way of generating the unique link for a user like `somesite.com/<hash>`?

Can a `UUID4` from Python be good enough? I feel that one can see that it is a `UUID4`, which would imply a Python service like `Flask` or `Django`. I wouldn't want to give out this information.

Comment: Virtually every computer language has some way to generate (various forms of) UUIDs, usually because the host OS has some ability to do so.  If you're worried that just using a UUID would leak server/language info, there's other ways for attackers to get that information (error pages being common), but it's not a terribly important thing to worry about overall.  Otherwise, could you just base64 encode a series of random bytes?

Comment: Could you clarify how to encode the series of random bytes? Should the seed change? And how many bits long  could it be?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, could you make this an answer so that I can upvote it?

Comment: There's too many unknowns for me to answer here, overall.  For one thing, many web frameworks have modules for handling registration, because getting it wrong has terrible consequences - see if whatever framework you're using will generate links for you, or has helpers for it.

Comment: I am interested in django. I have added a tag for it. Could you mention some of the many unknowns that you had in mind?